# MongoDB Mongoose Scheme Nested Document Structure and Relations

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, schema, mongoose-schema

I have a project with the following document flow.

Users -> Accounts -> Projects

**Users**

- Users have specific roles

**Accounts**

- CRUD conditioned by User role
- Specific users will have access to individual accounts. I was thinking to add an array userGroup with user id's?

**Projects**

- Nested under Accounts related to a single accountToken ID
- CRUD conditioned by User role
- Specific users will have access to individual projects.

Here are example Schema models simplified for demo purposes.

UserSchema.js:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
      unique: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['admin', 'user'],
      default: 'user'
    }
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

AccountSchema.js:

```
const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    accountName: {
      type: String,
    },
    accountToken: {
      type: String
    }
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
```

ProjectSchema.js:

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projectName: {
        type: String,
    },
    projectType: String,
    projectToken: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

I am stuck on the best way to setup nested or sub-document Schema Relations and the best way to relate the data between each other. Any guidance and suggestions would be a huge help! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
  type: String,
  required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
  unique: true,
},
role: {
  type: String,
  enum: ['admin', 'user'],
  default: 'user'
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

const AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     required: true,
     ref: 'User'
 },
 accountName: {
     type: String,
 },
accountToken: {
    type: String
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);

const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  accountTokenId:{
      type: String
  },
  projectName: {
      type: String,
  },
  projectType: String,
  projectToken: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Comment: Thanks @joshua-oweipadei. I ended up nesting the Project Schema inside the Account Schema `projects: [ProjectSchema]` and then using virtuals for the id. Probably not the best but it's working at the moment. [Example](https://gist.github.com/3daddict/0a19358c2d783fee8d15966666286a87)